# Time system for a python adventure game

Tags: python

Right so I have just started learning time stuff in Python and I am trying to make it that if the time is lets say `22:00` at night it would tell you that it is night time and the shops are closed. Here is what I have:

```
import time;

localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
print ('Local current time :', localtime)
```

I am sorry that I have to ask questions that are probably dumb but yeah...

Comment: I think you should start by exhaustively defining the times when you want to display that shops are open/closed.

Comment: You'll need to compare the time to both an opening time and closing time, or list of opening and closing times for individual shops. Try to code that yourself and post it if you get stuck.

Comment: import time

print
t = time.localtime()
print ('Day of month:', t.tm_mday)

if t.tm_mday == 8:
    print('ohhhh those russians')

Comment: this worked for what I needed the output was ohhhhh those russians

Comment: thanks guys for helping me again

Comment: i just tried this on my phone and it looks like it will work, you will need some more logic... best of luck
import time

t = time.localtime() 
if t.tm_hour >= 22:
    print("its late")
else:
    print("its not that late")